# Easier way to produce a list out of a nested list?

Tags: python

Using some numerical algorithm, my code produces a list of matrices, which is stored in a nested list, like follows

```
A = [matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]), matrix([[5,6],[7,8]]), ...)
```

Subsequently, I want to plot the values 1,5,9,... against some other list, say 'x', with the same length. At the moment I loop over the values I want like such

```
wanted_sol
for i in range(0,len(A))
   wanted_sol.append(A[i][0,0])
```

and then I plot 'wanted_sol'. I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do this? I tried several things like

```
plot(x, A[:][0,0])
plot(x, A[0:len(A)][0,0]),
```

but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Did you try List comprehension? `[A[i][0,0] for i in range(len(A))]`

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, come to think of it, I do know that method. However, I would prefer a method like "B[0:10]", to give the first 10 elements of a list B, but then for the case at hand.

Comment: @thefourtheye: The index is unnecessary: ``[m[0, 0] for m in A]`` should do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert A to `numpy.ndarray` and use numpy slice notation:

```
>>> A = np.array([np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]), np.matrix([[5,6],[7,8]])])
>>> A[:,0,0]
array([1, 5])
```